# Microsoft Edge resize issue on button hover

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Here is my html and css: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q7c4zmo/)

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}
.scroll {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
    <button>x</button>
    <div class="scroll">
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
        <div>testtesttesttest testtest</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover on the button on Microsoft Edge the inner div is being resized.

In this simple version, I can produce the error with button hover, but in my actual case the resizing occurs when I click anywhere on the window.

Comment: That is an odd behaviour... Something on hover triggers restyle of button, that affects sibling element with uncertain width dimension (extended with vertical scroll)... It's most likely a render bug, that can get solved with explicitly defining sibling elements width.

Comment: PS: It looks like Edge doesn't like uncertainty... Setting .scroll overflox-y to scroll instead of auto clears the problem. My guess is that when recalculation of elements styles and position happens on button hover, Edge removes scrollbar from .scroll, decreasing elements total width, then realizes it is exceeding max height, adds scrollbar again, but without considering adding it to total width - nudging it's content to break lines... It is all just an analytic guessing, i might be wrong.

Comment: In the end i don't think the problem is within HTML, CSS per se... You are just giving a hard time to edge with many uncertain values, that Edge doesn't apparently handle well.

Comment: Since the content is dynamic, I dont think I cant specify sibling width properly for all cases. Setting overflow-y to scroll is kind of solution to the problem, but still for short content I prefer not to show the scroll.

Comment: Issue reported - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11578955/ - @nilgun If there is no way (in your design) to make at least some style values "certain" instead of "automated", i don't think there is a way to solve your issue at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the perfect solution. 
Putting `display: inline` to `.scroll`l and again in hover state solving the problem.

Try this one edge 
[Code pen link](http://codepen.io/themirobin/pen/PpMObQ)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution clears off y-scrolling and max-height property.

Comment: I just tried with button border. if we set a border or border width 0 it not breaking the line.
Please check code pen link. I have updated that.

Comment: @MonirulIslam That is because you remove browser-based elements (button) default styling

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your comment. 
I guess we won't keep those button default at the end.  :)